# How to extract String value from com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference in Java?

Tags: java, windows, jna

I'm using

Dependency:
`implementation group: "net.java.dev.jna", name: "jna"`

Code:

```
PointerByReference phToken = new PointerByReference();
advapi32.LogonUserW(new WString(username), new WString(domain), new WString(password), 3, 0, phToken);
```

now i need to extract String value from this phToken, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your pointer from the reference:

`Pointer pointer = phToken.getValue();`

getValue() returns a Pointer

(https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.13.0/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.html)

and then convert the arguments to strings as needed, this is for the first argument:

`String Value1 = ptrParam1.getString(0)`

getXXX(offset) can be used to get a data type by offset
(https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.13.0/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Nils Hoffman indicated in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75772120/1161484), the first step is dereferencing the pointer from the ByReference, which would be

```java
Pointer tokenPointer = phToken.getValue();
```

If that pointer represents a `String`, on Windows you'd use `getWideString()` for the UTF16 version.  However, the Windows API docs don't indicate that this is a string.  The [LogonUserW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw) function you used says:

> `[out] phToken`
>
> A pointer to a handle variable that receives a handle to a token that represents the specified user.
>
> You can use the returned handle in calls to the ImpersonateLoggedOnUser function.
>
> In most cases, the returned handle is a primary token that you can use in calls to the CreateProcessAsUser function. However, if you specify the LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK flag, LogonUser returns an impersonation token that you cannot use in CreateProcessAsUser unless you call DuplicateTokenEx to convert it to a primary token.
>
> When you no longer need this handle, close it by calling the CloseHandle function.

So what you really have is a `HANDLE` which has internal meaning to Windows, but is not a String.  A [HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN#handle) is just a fancy name for a pointer:

> HANDLE     A handle to an object.
>
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
>
> typedef PVOID HANDLE;

So while it represents a user (the `username` you passed as a parameter to the function), it's just a 64-bit number, and not a String.

Given that you know the final parameter is a handle, you would probably want to pass a `HANDLEByReference` to begin with, as is already mapped in JNA's [user contributions](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/e96f30192e9455e7cc4117cce06fc3fa80bead55/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.java#L632).